# Nextflow: permission denied for files in bin with -rwxrwxr-x permissions granted

Tags: permissions, nextflow

I've made a fresh install of nextflow in a new computer, and I was trying to test the nf-core/rnaseq pipeline, but I am receiving the following error when executing:

```
Error executing process > 'NFCORE_RNASEQ:RNASEQ:INPUT_CHECK:SAMPLESHEET_CHECK (samplesheet.csv)'

Command error:
  .command.sh: line 3: /media/Data/nextflow-rnaseq/rnaseq/bin/check_samplesheet.py: Permission denied
```

I've checked the permissions for the file, and has all the executing permissions:`-rwxrwxr-x`. I've also tried to execute it using both my working environment and singularity, and keep finding the same error.

I've also tested my own pipeline, with another project root folder and its own bin folder with custom scripts in there, and I'm having the same error.

Does anyone know if I'm missing something I should have done to make the scripts in bin accessible to nextflow?

Nextflow version: 22.04.4.5706

Comment: I vaguely remember running into this issue before. If I recall correctly it has something to do with a faulty shebang in the .py file?

Comment: I'm not sure that this issue is caused by that, but it could be. I'm using the exact same file they have available at github (literally git clone https://github.com/nf-core/rnaseq.git), and the shebang in the file is #!/usr/bin/env python3. I'm able to launch it using python3 outside nextflow. Please if you see anything wrong on what I'm describing let me know.

Comment: But do you get permission denied when you call it directly? I.e. what is the output of: `/media/Data/nextflow-rnaseq/rnaseq/bin/check_samplesheet.py`? Check to see how  `/media/Data` was mounted. You will get permission denied if your filesystem was mounted with `noexec` for example. Please update your question to include the output of `mount | grep /media`.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's the issue. I wasn't aware that the filesystem was mounted without execution permission. After solving that the bin folder works properly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve pointed out in a comment, the issue was related to how the filesystem was mounted (noexec), and fixing that solves the problem